# Click an HTML button/link on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, popup

I have implemented various methods on this forum, and cannot figure out a solution.

I simply need to open a popup button on pageload.

Here is the test page: [test page](http://miracleweightloss.club/videotest)

Here is the code that I am currently working with:

```
<script>
window.setTimeout('clickit()',5000);
function clickit(){
   location.href = document.getElementById("fmp-button");
}
</script>

<a href="#" rel="487d7c3e5cb0edeabb176a823a117ad8" id="fmp-button"><img src="https://assets.fortumo.com/fmp/fortumopay_150x50_red.png" width="150" height="50" alt="Mobile Payments by Fortumo" border="0" id="popup"/></a>

<script src='https://assets.fortumo.com/fmp/fortumopay.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:** Solved. (see correct answer below)

FYI, you may need to increase the number to 1000 or 2000. 500 does not work.

Comment: `$("#fmp-button").click()`

Comment: Your code is assigning the browser url to a dom element. What do you mean by open a popup button? Do you want to trigger the anchor link and redirect the page to that link? or display some dialog/popup? Can you elaborate a bit more, please?

Comment: I should add, it is an image link. However I have tried onclick by ID, and it does not work.

Comment: If you add this code to your page, you will see a button. Click this button and you get a popup payment window. I have tried using javascript (onload click id). However, it only shows the href (#), and not the popup. When I click with my mouse, I get a popup.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to show this **specific** payment dialog when your page load (instead of when user click), or do you want to build your own dialog (different stuff from this demo)? sorry, it's not clear.

Comment: I want to automatically click the button. When I click it works fine. When the javascript clicks, it shows this "#" but doesn't popup. Did you try clicking the button yourself? It should popup a payment window.

Comment: Please, check my answer and the fiddle. It's working there.

Comment: By the way it still isn't working on my page. Here is the code: <script>
window.setTimeout(clickit, 500);
function clickit(){
   document.getElementById("fmp-button").click();
}
</script>
<a href="#" rel="487d7c3e5cb0edeabb176a823a117ad8" id="fmp-button"><img src="https://assets.fortumo.com/fmp/fortumopay_150x50_red.png" width="150" height="50" alt="Mobile Payments by Fortumo" border="0" id="popup"/></a>
<script src='https://assets.fortumo.com/fmp/fortumopay.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, @CheapCoolGifts. You can accept the answer if you think it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
window.setTimeout(clickit, 500);

function clickit(){
   document.getElementById("fmp-button").click();
}
```

Explaining what happens:

1) `.setTimeout` receives a function. You were passing a `String`; you can also pass an `anonymous function` and trigger your function from inside:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { clickit(); }, 500);
```

2) `document.getElementById("fmp-button")` returns the element with the ID `fmp-button`.

3) `.click` method "simulates" user click (triggers the link, as if it was an user clicking)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/mvrvdL7c/

Comment: Can you check the fiddle? it loads the dialog when the page loads.

Comment: Your page is not rendering this script properly: There is a **syntax error**. check your console or source code. You're rendering html elements (`<p>` tag) inside your javascript code.

Comment: How did you do that without using this script as well: <script src='https://assets.fortumo.com/fmp/fortumopay.js' type='text/javascript'></script> ?

Comment: In jsfiddle, you load external scripts in the left panel (external resources).

Answer (score 0):

Edited my answer

How about this?

```
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">



<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200,height=100");
}
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

var id = '#dialog';
 
//Get the screen height and width
var maskHeight = $(document).height();
var maskWidth = $(window).width();
 
//Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

//transition effect
$('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
$('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9); 
 
//Get the window height and width
var winH = $(window).height();
var winW = $(window).width();
              
//Set the popup window to center
$(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
$(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
 
//transition effect
$(id).fadeIn(2000);  
 
//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
//Cancel the link behavior
e.preventDefault();

$('#mask').hide();
$('.window').hide();
});

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
$(this).hide();
$('.window').hide();
});
 
});
```

```css
#mask {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  background-color: #000;
  display: none;
}

#boxes .window {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 440px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

#boxes #dialog {
  width: 750px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

#popupfoot {
  font-size: 16pt;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script> 
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="dialog" class="window">
    Your Content Goes Here
    <div id="popupfoot"> <a href="#" class="close agree">I agree</a> | <a class="agree"style="color:red;" href="#">I do not agree</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mask"></div>
</div>
```